# Convert SQL columns to rows with an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, while-loop

I have  data that is 192 separate columns. They are column pairs so that there is data for a 15 minute time slice and a quality control number. The way it is setup now each row represents a single day. I would like to insert the data into another table with fewer columns (Date,ReadTime,QualityControlNumber,Reading,...)
I started with trying a while loop like this but using a variable to change the column header doesn't seem possible.

Should I nest while loops to increment the column headers or is there another trick I should be using

Code tried:

```
Declare @count varchar (10), 
    @QC varchar (10), 
    @Interval varchar(10) 
set @count = 1 
set @QC = 'QC#' + @count 
set @Interval = 'Interval#' + @count 

While (@count<97) 
    BEGIN 
        insert into Data_DATEstr (Number,[ReadDate],TimeInterval,QCReading,IntervalReading,ConversionFactor) 
        select [Number], [Start Date], @count, ['QC#'+@count], [Interval# +@count] ,[Conversion Factor] 
        from table 
        where [Number] = '103850581' 
            and [Start Date] = '060112' 

        set @count = (@count+1) 
    END
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and then the expected result?

Comment: Why do you need loops? Can't you use simple use `INSERT INTO SecondTable (<columns of the second table>) SELECT <just a few columns> FROM OriginalTable WHERE <some condition>`

Comment: Please do not paste code samples into comments; it is hard to read. Please Edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a while-loop for this.  You want an [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) If you are trying to convert 192 separate columns to rows, then you will definitely want to use an `UNPIVOT` function.  This can be written using dynamic SQL so then you will have have to code all of the fields:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('test') and
               C.name like 'col%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'SELECT QualityControlNumber, replace(col, ''col'', '''')  as col, value
            from test
            unpivot 
            (
               value
               for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f406/2)

Using dynamic SQL for this will get the list of fields that you want to transpose when the query is executed. This also prevents you having to manually code for 192 separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not entirely clear, it sounds like you need some form of operation similar to [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  This lets you rotate columns into rows.  I'd suggest reading up on it and seeing if it will work for you -- even if it doesn't, it might suggest an approach that would work.

Answer (score 0):

The command that you want is unpivot.  Something like:

```
select Date, ReadTime, QualityControlNumber, Reading
from t
unpivot (Reading for date in (day1,  . . . , dayn) as unpvt
```

You will find that you won't really get the date, but instead the original column name.  You can fix this by putting the unpivot query in a subquery (or CTE) and then using string manipulations and cast to convert the column name to a date.